# PHP PECL oauth error "Unknown signature method"

Tags: php, oauth, provider, pecl

I get an Exception on my production server when i try to instanciate the class "OAuthProvider" from pecl package oauth.

```
try {
    $oauth = new OAuthProvider();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // Get the error here
}
```

The error message is : "Unknown signature method"

Have anyone got this error ?

Comment: How are you calling the script? It expects a web request at the very least; otherwise, if you want to test it from the command line you have to enter those parameters in the constructor as an array.

Comment: I call the script in a simple web request with an oauth signature or not.

Comment: Assuming you're using Authorization header style, what's the contents of `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` or the values of `$_POST`, `$_GET` ... anything!

Comment: $_GET is empty, $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] is empty too. $_POST contain one value 'url' => 'oauth/...' but i set  $oauth->setParam('url', NULL); to ignore this value. I confirmed "the unknown signature method" appear only on my prod server when my request is not a oauth request (no oauth header), but on my dev server (local => apache on macport) there is no problem.

Comment: Now on oauth request, i have another problem => $token = sha1(OAuthProvider::generateToken(20,true)); take more than 30s to execute so my script is blocked. I don't understand why this method didn't work on my server ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuthProvider looks for the oauth_signature_method in either the Authorization header or REQUEST params (respectively) if you run a non-CLI SAPI.

Under the CLI SAPI you can set the parameters in the ctor:

```
$op = new OAuthProvider(array("oauth_signature_method" => OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1));
```

Comment: No, it does not use REQUEST. Only `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV`.

Answer (score 0):

This is [PHP bug #68168](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68168) - some servers have an empty `$_SERVER[HTTP_AUTHORIZATION]` value, which is not correctly detected by the php oauth extension.